# "Responsive" Chart.js chart is taller than the containing window

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am using the Chart.js library to create a series of charts.  I am noticing that when specifying the option "responsive:true", while the canvas does indeed contrain itself to the page width, it does not constrain itself to the page height, even when full screen.  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/uxtb9wj9/

StackOverflow necessitates that I accompany a jsfiddle link with code, so here it is:

HTML

```
<div class="row chartArea">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="chartArea">
        <canvas id="chart" style="height: auto !important;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function widgetCallback(response) {
    console.log("widgetCallback; response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    var chartData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

    //Some dummy values - delete later
    var labels = chartData['chart1']['labels'];
    var dataSet1Title = chartData['chart1']['dataTitle'];
    var dataSet2Title = chartData['chart2']['dataTitle'];
    var dataSet1Data = chartData['chart1']['data'];
    var dataSet2Data = chartData['chart2']['data'];

    Chart.types.Line.extend({
        name: "Line2Y",
        getScale: function (data) {
            var startPoint = this.options.scaleFontSize;
            var endPoint = this.chart.height - (this.options.scaleFontSize * 1.5) - 5;
            return Chart.helpers.calculateScaleRange(
            data,
            endPoint - startPoint,
            this.options.scaleFontSize,
            this.options.scaleBeginAtZero,
            this.options.scaleIntegersOnly,
            this.options.scaleLabel);
        },
        initialize: function (data) {
            var y2datasetLabels = [];
            var y2data = [];
            var y1data = [];
            data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                if (dataset.y2axis == true) {
                    y2datasetLabels.push(dataset.label);
                    y2data = y2data.concat(dataset.data);
                } else {
                    y1data = y1data.concat(dataset.data);
                }
            });

            // use the helper function to get the scale for both datasets
            var y1Scale = this.getScale(y1data);
            this.y2Scale = this.getScale(y2data);
            var normalizingFactor = y1Scale.max / this.y2Scale.max;

            // update y2 datasets
            data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                if (y2datasetLabels.indexOf(dataset.label) !== -1) {
                    dataset.data.forEach(function (e, j) {
                        dataset.data[j] = e * normalizingFactor;
                    })
                }
            })

            // denormalize tooltip for y2 datasets
            this.options.multiTooltipTemplate = function (d) {
                if (y2datasetLabels.indexOf(d.datasetLabel) !== -1) return Math.round(d.value / normalizingFactor, 6);
                else return d.value;
            }

            Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        draw: function () {
            this.scale.xScalePaddingLeft = 60;
            this.scale.xScalePaddingRight = this.scale.xScalePaddingLeft + 30;
            Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

            this.chart.ctx.textAlign = "center";
            this.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
            this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = "#666";

            var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
            ctx.save();
            // position
            var x = this.scale.xScalePaddingLeft * 0.4;
            var y = this.chart.height / 2;
            // change origin
            ctx.translate(x, y)
            // rotate text
            ctx.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);
            ctx.fillText(this.datasets[0].label, 0, 0);
            ctx.fillText(this.datasets[1].label, 0, this.chart.width - 60);
            ctx.restore();

            var yStep = (this.scale.endPoint - this.scale.startPoint) / this.y2Scale.steps
            for (var i = 0, y = this.scale.endPoint, label = this.y2Scale.min;
            i <= this.y2Scale.steps;
            i++) {
                this.chart.ctx.fillText(label, this.chart.width - this.scale.xScalePaddingRight + 20, y);
                y -= yStep;
                label += this.y2Scale.stepValue
            }
        }
    });


    var lineChartData1 = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: dataSet1Title,
            fillColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            data: dataSet1Data
        }, {
            label: dataSet2Title,
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            data: dataSet2Data,
            y2axis: true
        }]
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

    var myLine1 = new Chart(ctx).Line2Y(lineChartData1, {
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        scaleShowGridLines: false,
        responsive: true,
        scaleShowLabels: true,
        showTooltips: true,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %>"
    });
}

var response = '{"chart1":{"data":["826","748","76","58"],"labels":["10-08","10-09","10-10","10-11"],"labelTitle":"Date","dataTitle":"Uniques","title":"Uniques"},"chart2":{"data":["2018.00","2095.40","156.00","23.76"],"labels":["10-08","10-09","10-10","10-11"],"labelTitle":"Date","dataTitle":"Revenue","title":"Revenue"},"title":"Chart Title"}';
widgetCallback(response);
```

EXTERNAL RESOURCES

jQuery 2.1.4, Bootstrap CSS 3.0, Chart.js 1.0.2

(In the fiddle, just adjust the size of the "Result" section to be about twice as wide as it is tall, and re-run the fiddle.)

How can I get the chart to constrain itself not only to window width but height as well?  Thank you!

Comment: The screen total height?

Comment: Screen total height will vary depending on device, etc.

Comment: use window.innerHeight.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea using the viewport height on your case. That's fairly easy in [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        * {padding: 0; height: 0;}
        canvas { width: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }
        ]
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight;
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the integration of this.  If I put it immediately prior to the draw code, `var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;`, it does not resolve the issue.  If I add it to the draw function within the extended line chart object, it messes up data display.  Can you suggest where your fix should be applied?

Comment: Thanks for the edit - however, unfortunately, that is where I tried inserting the snippet, and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @squaretastic Not sure, but `ctx.canvas.height` is a readonly attribute.

Comment: I played around with your suggestion, and this seems to work: `var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
 ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.9;
    
    var myLine1 = new Chart(ctx).Line2Y(lineChartData1, {
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        scaleShowGridLines: false,
        scaleShowLabels: true,
        showTooltips: true,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %>"
    });`  I updated the fiddle as well to reflect this: http://jsfiddle.net/uxtb9wj9/.

Comment: @squaretastic Very nice!  I forget to mention that `window.innerHeight` take into account the horizontal scrollbar height, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The key seems to be in these three changes:
1) Not using the "responsive: true" option provided by the library
2) Setting both the width AND height explicitly
3) Setting the height to 90% instead of 100% of window.innerHeight, as otherwise it still is taller than the containing window.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.9; 
var myLine1 = new Chart(ctx).Line2Y(lineChartData1, { scaleBeginAtZero: true, scaleShowGridLines: false, scaleShowLabels: true, showTooltips: true, tooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %>" });
```